# Android : show a english number string into hindi or any language number string

Tags: java, android, number-formatting

I have an edit text. I have to take the string from the edit text and the edit text will provide some numbers into English formate. and then I have to show the number in Hindi or any kind of language format in a text view

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you are actually want to translate / convert numbers in your editText to another language.

First approach,
I would suggest you to implement Google Translate API. Since you mentioned an editText, assuming only 1, and maybe for some Q and A?!

The second approach, you mentioned about formatting, the number index came into my mind. You could use [Locale Directories and Resource Files](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#CreateDirs)